# Se me tachan los métodos de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

[Cuando llamo metodos como ready o click de jQuery se me tachan como se ve en la imagen, no me da ningún error, pero quería saber el por que sucede eso y como se podría solucionar.

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pista: ¿colocaste el mouse sobre el método? ¿ves algún mensaje?

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos tachados suelen significar que están deprecated. Puedes cambiar el `click()` por `on()`

Aún así el método `click` de JQuery no está deprecated por lo que puede que te lo marque de esa manera por algún plugin del IDE que interfiera y provoque que no coja correctamente la referencia del método.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, ya cambie el método click por el on y todo bien